# Is it possible to edit android apps from Google play

Tags: google-play-store, google-apps

If I want to customize the way an app looks is there a way to do so ?
I am thinking in the lines of obtaining source code and editing.

Comment: If the developer publishes their source code, sure.  The Play Store is not an open source repository.

Answer (score 2):

Unless an app is open-source (freeware), doing so is illegal and is an infringement to the End User License Agreement.

However, if you talking about open-source apps, you can request the developers to send you a copy of the source code for any changes/editing. You can find the contact details of the developers in the Play Store page of the app.

Comment: But how would I know if the app is open source?

Comment: There is almost always a mention that the app is open-source in the description. Note that an app can be free and be closed-source.